# how to monitor gearmand daemon by Monit?

Tags: gearman, monit

So the configuration file for monitoring gearman server is:

```
set logfile /var/log/monit.log

check process gearmand with pidfile /var/run/gearmand.pid
    start program = "sudo gearmand --pid-file=/var/run/gearmand.pid"
    stop program = "sudo kill all gearmand"

    if failed port 4730 protocol http then restart
```

from monit.log

```
[EST Nov 26 19:42:39] info     : 'gearmand' start: sudo
[EST Nov 26 19:42:39] error    : Error: Could not execute sudo
[EST Nov 26 19:43:09] error    : 'gearmand' failed to start
```

but Monit says that process failed to start. Does anyone know how to make it work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Has the process actually failed to start, or is it just Monit that can't detect that its running? Whats the monit output?

Comment: There is your first problem - monit does not appear to be able to run 'sudo', you need to investigate that first before worrying about anything to with Gearmand

Comment: did you succeed? would be nice to know if you have a solution and if yes, please describe it.

Comment: plz do share if you were able to find a solution to this !

Answer (score 0):

```
check process gearman_daemon with pidfile /var/run/gearmand/gearmand.pid
    start program = "/bin/bash -c '/usr/sbin/gearmand -d --job-retries 3 --log-file /var/log/gearmand/gearmand.log --pid-file /var/run/gearmand/gearmand.pid --queue-type libsqlite3 --libsqlite3-db /var/tmp/gearman-queue.sqlite3'"
    stop program = "/bin/bash -c '/bin/killall gearmand'"
```